# Firebase bridging header not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift2, bridging-header

I'm building a Firebase app in swift, I installed the cocoa pod correctly then created an Objective-C file so it would make me a bridging header. When I try to import Firebase elsewhere in the app it says no such module found. I tried to build anyway because sometimes the error will go away but it failed.

Should I do something with my build settings? I've created bridging headers before and never had too (I thought Xcode did that automatically). I'm using version 7.2.1 (the latest) by the way.

Thanks for the help!

```
#ifndef FirebaseNetwork_Bridging_Header_h
#define FirebaseNetwork_Bridging_Header_h

#import <Firebase/Firebase.h>

#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

The documentation from firebase says to use import Firebase when in swift.  This however causes errors at compile time.  After adding the bridging header and importing Firebase.h inside of it, you will be able to access the Firebase api in your swift files.

Comment: I thought that could have been the problem but it is there, XCode put it there automatically and it still doesn't work.

Comment: This may be a silly question but did you add import Firebase to the top of your swift file? https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/quickstart.html

Comment: Haha, yes I did. It's saying no such module exists, even when I build and run the error doesn't go away.

Comment: What else could it possibly be? Firebase doesn't tell you to add user_frameworks to the podfile so I didn't, could that be it?

Comment: Ya, I don't think that would be it.  Personally I have never used firebase so I am not super familiar with the framework.  Let me make a quick test project with that pod to see what I see

Comment: So I setup my bridging header just like yours and built.  the import Firebase line still complains, but without it, I am able to access the Firebase methods in the code.  I just added a simple call to see if it would complie let isFocused = Firebase.accessibilityElementIsFocused()  It compiled without error. (Just a warning that my line is useless) :)

Comment: How weird! I can access it too. Figured I wouldn't be able to but maybe in the newest version they made it so that importing isn't necessary. Thanks again.

Comment: My pleasure! Glad you're up and running!!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to insert the following line in your Podfile:

`use_frameworks!`

Then open the .xcworkspace file. Clean the build. Compile it.